# Como fazer um UPDATE usando dados de duas tabelas diferentes?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Era uma vez a tabela:

```
Id   dado1  dado2  
01   1000   10  
02   1234   12  
03   9999   1
```

Eu tinha uma tarefa `cron` que executava a seguinte atualização diariamente:

```
UPDATE tabela1 SET dado1 = dado1 + dado2;
```

Só que pra organizar as coisas, movi `dado2` pra outra tabela.

Aí tentei:

```
UPDATE tabela1 SET dado1 = dado1 + tabela2.dado2;
```

mas não deu certo.

As duas tabelas tem `id`, mas como faço para usar o `id` a fim de que cada linha do `UPDATE`  em `tabela1` use o `dado2` do seu respectivo `id`?

Comment: Comece postando aqui estrutura das tabelas

Comment: sem ver a estrutura da tabela é difícil, mas tenta algo do tipo UPDATE tabela1, tabela2 SET tabela1.dado1 = tabela1.dado1 + tabela2.dado2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa unir as duas pela chave em comum de ambas:

```
 UPDATE     tabela1
 INNER JOIN tabela2 ON tabela1.id = tabela2.id
 SET        tabela1.dado1 = tabela1.dado1 + tabela2.dado2;
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/466e8/1)**.

Importante saber que na cláusula `ON` deve ser especificada a condição que une as duas tabelas. Atenção se os campos tiverem nomes diferentes em cada tabela, para não inverter no `ON` ou esquecer de ajustar algum dos lados.

Se quiser, antes de mexer na tabela, teste o `ON` com um `SELECT` para ver se está tudo em ordem antes de modificar os dados:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM tabela1
 INNER JOIN tabela2 ON tabela1.id = tabela2.id;
```

Escolhemos `INNER JOIN` por que estamos atualizando a `tabela1` com dados da `tabela2`, então não nos interessam linhas em que não houver correspondência entre as tabelas.

**Importante:** estamos partindo do pressuposto que a relação seja 1:1. Caso tenha IDs repetidos em qualquer uma das tabelas, o valor será somado mais de uma vez (mas aí é uma decisão de arquitetura, e não um problema na *query* especificamente).

Para entender melhor qual `JOIN` usar em cada caso, veja esta postagem:

> [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/70)

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer manipulações com mais de uma tabela use o comando `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE tabela1 JOIN tabela2 SET dado1 = dado1 + tabela2.dado2;
```